# Access the current environment (development, production, etc.) from within the builder setup in .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net-core, environment-variables, authorization, .net-6.0

I am building an app in .NET 6 that uses authentication and policy-based authorization. Both function well. However, I need to create a way to bypass authorization within a development environment. Below is my code in *program.cs*.

I have created a class that disables authorization and added this to the builder `builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, DisableAuthorization>();`  This works fine and all I need to do now is make it conditional upon the environment being "development." My problem is that I do not know how to get the current environment from *within the builder* (I do know how to do it once it has been built - e.g., `app.Environment.IsDevelopment()`).

I have searched online but all of the solutions I could find involve injection into the Startup() and ConfigureServices() methods - both of which have been replaced by the *WebApplication.CreateBuilder* in .NET 6.

What is the most efficient way to get the environment prior to building the application?

**Current Code (*Program.cs*)**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAppState, AppState>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, IsAdminHandler>();
...


//Add authentication and register CAS as the authentication handler
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)

    // Add cookie authentication
    ...

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        // Add access policies
        options.AddPolicy("IsAdmin", Policies.IsAdminPolicy());
        options.AddPolicy("IsManager", Policies.IsManagerPolicy());
        options.AddPolicy("IsUser", Policies.IsUserPolicy());
        options.AddPolicy("IsReadOnly", Policies.IsReadOnlyPolicy());

        // Add fallback authorization which blocks unauthenticated access to all pages
        // unless the [AllowAnonymous] attribute is applied to the route in the controller
        options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
    }
);

// Disable authorization in DEV
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, DisableAuthorization>();

// Run the builder and return the configured application to "app" 
var app = builder.Build();


// Configure the HTTP request pipeline by adding middleware
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    // Use detailed exception page (for development environment only)
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

    // Require HTTPS connection.  The default HSTS value is 30 days. 
    app.UseHsts();
}
else if (app.Environment.IsProduction())
{

    // Enable standard error page
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");

    // Require HTTPS connection. The default HSTS value is 30 days. 
    // You may want to change this for production scenarios, 
    // see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}
else
{
    throw new GenericException("Environment has not been set or is incorrect");
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`Environment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.webapplicationbuilder.environment?view=aspnetcore-6.0) property on [`WebApplicationBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.webapplicationbuilder?view=aspnetcore-6.0):

```cs
var isDev = builder.Environment.IsDevelopment();
```